# Replacing Middle Part of String Occurring Multiple Times

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file, that has variations of this line multiple times:
`source = "git::https://github.com/ORGNAME/REPONAME.git?ref=develop"`

I am passing through a tag name in a variable. I want to find every line that starts with `source` and update that line in the file to be 
`source = "git::https://github.com/ORGNAME/REPONAME.git?ref=$TAG"`

This should be able to be done with awk and sed, but having some difficulty making it work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Best,
Keren

Edit: In this scenario, the it says "develop", but it could also be set to "feature/test1" or "0.0.1" as well.

Edit2: The line with "source" is also indented by three or four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*source.*[?]ref=\)[^"]*\("\)/\1'"$TAG"'\2/' file
```

Comment: Hey Jahid. Thanks for the answer. This one works for me, but I just realized that the line with "source" is also indented by 4 spaces. How would I make this work with that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

with sed

```
$ sed '/^source/s/ref=develop"$/ref=$TAG"/' file
```

replace ref=develop" at the end of line with ref=$TAG" for lines starting with source.